# typescript - detect if the div is overflow with text (not working if -webkit-scrollbar display is set to none)

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

Below mentioned code works fine if the scrollbar is visible. But it stops working once i use

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {display: none;}
```

and

```
-ms-overflow-style: none; scrollbar-width: none;
```

MY working code if scrollbar is visible

Html

```
    <div #theElementYouWantToCheck><button *ngIf="checkOverflow(theElementYouWantToCheck)">More</button</div>
```

Ts

```
   checkOverflow (element) {
return element.offsetHeight < element.scrollHeight ||
       element.offsetWidth < element.scrollWidth;}
```

Comment: Try using `overflow:hidden` if you want not see the scroll bars

Comment: @Eliseo I dont want scroll bars to be visible.